# Not able to connect mongodb from spring boot using .pem file

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have .pem file which I received from my DBA, I used below command to convert it to jks file

**keytool -importcert -file global-bundle.pem -keystore truststore.jks -alias mongodbCA -storepass changeme**

After above change I got jks file which I kept in my resources folder. Below I have added in my application.properties file

**spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:mypassword@myhost:27017/profiledb-qa?ssl=true&sslContext=file:classpath:/truststore.jks&sslContextPassword=changeme**

I am using 2.7.2 spring boot version and used **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb** for mongo db.
After doing all of this still I m getting below error

***javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|73|cluster-rtt-ClusterId{value='65aa6a097c45ac56c573966e', description='null'}-:27017|2024-01-19 17:54:41.931 IST|SSLSocketImpl.java:1780|close the SSL connection (passive)
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
"throwable" : {
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target***

I have tried various ways but could not solve it, can anybody help me to understand the issue.

Comment: According to [Connection String URI Format](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.3/reference/connection-string/) neither `sslContext` nor `sslContextPassword` are valid connection string attributes. Certificates are provided by file, not any certificate storage.